# jQuery replacing mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I'm trying to replace the mouse cursor with an image.

I have the following html:

```
<div id="content-bg">
   <img src="path"/>
</div>
<div id="mouse"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#content-bg{
    background:url(../img/frontend/content-bg.png) top left no-repeat;
    width: 968px;
    height: 552px;
    position:relative;
}

#mouse {
     cursor: none;
     width: 75px;
     height: 76px;
     background: url("../img/frontend/cross.png") no-repeat center;
     position: absolute;
    display:none;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 10000;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#content-bg').mouseout(function(){
          $('#mouse').hide();
          $(this).css("cursor","none");
          return false;
     });
     $('#content-bg').mouseenter(function(){
          $('#mouse').show();
          return false;
     });
     $('#content-bg').mousemove(function(e){
          var x = e.clientX - $(document).scrollLeft() - 37.5;
          var y = e.clientY + $(document).scrollTop() - 38;
          $('#mouse').css('left', x).css('top',y);
     });
});
```

The mouse image is on the right place but seems to be blinking and flashy. The transitions aren't as smooth as I wanted. Somehow it seems that the `mouseout` and `mouseenter` events are triggered every time I move the mouse inside the content-bg div.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: That's becaue your mouse div is hiding the `content-bg`, so the mouse "left" it, then enter again. You need to thing on other way, or leave it...

Comment: Did you try to change the offset where the image is shown? Instead of removing half width/height try to add it. Without it I'm not sure it won't trigger the mouseout even because of the moved div itself

Comment: @gdoron But if I take out the - half dimensions it works just fine... Could you suggest a better approach or point me to some docs please?

Comment: @Adriano Yes you're actually right but then the mouse image won't be placed on the correct spot... If I remove half width/height all works fine apart from the image being on the wrong spot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out in comments, your `mouseout` occurs when your mouse suddenly hovers `#mouse`, as it appears.

You need to cancel out these events manually:

```
 $('#content-bg').mouseout(function(e){
      if($(e.relatedTarget).is('#mouse')) { return false; }
      $('#mouse').hide();
      $(this).css("cursor","none");
      return false;
 });

 $('#content-bg').mouseenter(function(e){
      if($(e.fromElement).is('#mouse')) { return false; }
      $('#mouse').show();
      return false;
 });
```

Comment: You didn't defined `e` in your code what is it? the event of jQuery has `fromElement` propety?

Comment: @gdoron: oops, sorry, I forgot to modify that when copying your code. `e` is the event that is being passed to the listener.

Comment: But there is no `fromElement` property in [jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). I guess both should be `relatedTarget`.

Comment: Yes it works! Still a bit rusty though (i guess) due to the events being triggered without need but it's the answer to my question!! If someone actually knows a better approach to this problem would be awesome ;) Thanks!!